# jqueryMobile change background color on swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Iam trying to set the background with jquery after it has swiped like this:

```
$( ".barcode-label" ).on( "swipeleft", function(){
        $('.barcode-label').addClass("swiped");
        $('.btn-swipe').removeClass('fa-angle-left');
        $('.btn-swipe').addClass('fa-angle-right');

        if($('.btn-swipe').hasClass('fa-angle-right')){
            console.log('check');
            $('btn-swipe').css('top', '93px');
            $('btn-swipe').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
```

and here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4zmn62g/)

I really don't get it why it is not changing its background could someone explain me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did forget to put the dot of class -.-"

```
    if($('.btn-swipe').hasClass('fa-angle-right')){
        console.log('check');
        $('.btn-swipe').css('top', '93px');
        $('.btn-swipe').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
```

Comment: ...and missed a dot position again: `$(.'btn-swipe').css('top', '93px');`